# How to extract a substring of certain length after matching pattern in R?

Tags: r, substring

I have a list of string: `string = c("PT11201320360429", "POSTEST1120122380820", "POST_TEST1120122380820")`. I need to get a vector of string that contains only the FOUR numbers after PT11, POSTEST11, or POST_TEST11 (i.e.2013, 2012, or 2012). How can I do this in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to extract 4 digits which occur after one of `PT11|POSTEST11|POST_TEST11`.

```
sub("(PT11|POSTEST11|POST_TEST11)(\\d{4}).*", "\\2", string)
#[1] "2013" "2012" "2012"
```

Answer (score 0):

As the 4 numbers occur after 11, we can capture that as a group and in the replacement use the backreference of the captured group

```
sub("^P.*11(....).*", "\\1", string)
#[1] "2013" "2012" "2012"
```

Or make it shorter with

```
sub("^\\D+11(.{4}).*", "\\1", string)
#[1] "2013" "2012" "2012"
```

#### data

```
string <- c("PT11201320360429", "POSTEST1120122380820", "POST_TEST1120122380820")
```